# Text append performance in Haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

I realized that appending multiple instances of `Text` in Haskell is much slower than concatenating a list of texts. For instance, `T.concat ["'", txt, "'"]` is almost twice faster than

```
"'" `T.append` txt `T.append` "'"
```

This is because any `append` actually creates a new intermediate instance of `Text`, while `concat` makes a single instance.

I am working on a project that does a lot of text appends.
I wonder if there is a simple way to optimize such cases?
One option is to replace all such occurrences by hand.
The other option is to use GHC rewriting rules to convert them to the `concat` form.
Is the rewriting rule a reasonable option? How can I write such a rule then?
What are the other options?

Comment: [`Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.1/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder.html) is specifically for this purpose.

Comment: That's a good point, but I am working on a code base that is already heavily using non-lazy text appends. I wonder if there is a quick & easy fix for that or not.

Comment: You could also use lists or DLists of Text-s, and then concatenate after you've done building. If you can't separate building and concatenating, and definitely need appends, then probably Text isn't the right structure for the job.

Comment: I have lots of substring replacement, e.g., replace `%key%i%` with `value-i` in a million Text instances. I have tens of such replacement rules. These can easily be replaces by `concat` of list of Texts or lazy Texts or Builders or whatever. My question is that if I can use [GHC rewrite rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) to replace `append`s with `concat`s, and if it is a good idea if possible at all.

Comment: I think simply replacing `append`-s by `concat` in the source is definitely better than rewrite rules. Rewrite rules is a rather intricate feature meant for library writers who would like to provide optimizations for users without exposing the plumbing. In production code they'd just add complexity and obscure the semantics as it is in the code.

Comment: @AndrásKovács: I updated the source code and replace most of the text building functionality with `Lazy Text Builder`s. Now, about 12 percent of the program runtime is in [`unstream/resize`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.1/docs/src/Data-Text-Internal-Fusion.html#unstream) block. I wonder if there is a way to optimize this one? I guess the answer is no.

Comment: Rewrite rules are pretty tricky, and not the most reliable things in general.